# Using google maps api to get the location of the users and other users in the vicinity

Tags: android, google-maps, location, maps

So, I am thinking of creating this app which is based on the location, (not a dating app) for android, and I got stumbled on a question, can we use google maps api to get the location of the current user using my app(i know we can do the first one) and then based on that location, find the other users using that app in the same vicinity, like in 1-5km's or some distance, can we do that? If so, can someone give me rough idea on doing that? Like where should I get started and everything, because I am a newbie and currently in the "learning" phase of android. Just the rough Idea will be enough.

Comment: `can we use google maps api to get the location of the current user`. No. A map will not tell you. You need to use the gps for that.

Comment: yeah, i thought there's some abracadabra involved. It is a simple question, i know i will have to use GPS for the location, but what do i have to do for finding the users in the vicinity of some user?

Answer (score 2):

Any way Android devices unable to communicate on air in such way. You will need server. And you will need get GPS coordinates of your users, send them to server periodically. Filter last coordinates on server side, and by user's request send back list of coordinates people near you. And with use of Google Maps API (or another map service) show them to user. Its in general.